# Is there any code Optimization method for the following c++ program

Tags: c++, optimization, loops, for-loop

```
        BYTE * srcData;
        BYTE * pData;

        int i,j;
        int srcPadding;

                    //some variable initialization

        for (int r = 0;r < h;r++,srcData+= srcPadding)
        {
            for (int col = 0;col < w;col++,pData += 4,srcData += 3)
            {
                memcpy(pData,srcData,3);        
            }
        }
```

I've tried loop unrolling, but it helps little.

```
        int segs = w / 4;
        int remain = w - segs * 4; 

        for (int r = 0;r < h;r++,srcData+= srcPadding)
        {
            int idx = 0;
            for (idx = 0;idx < segs;idx++,pData += 16,srcData += 12)
            {
                memcpy(pData,srcData,3);
                *(pData + 3) = 0xFF;
                memcpy(pData + 4,srcData + 3,3);
                *(pData + 7) = 0xFF;
                memcpy(pData + 8,srcData + 6,3);
                *(pData + 11) = 0xFF;
                memcpy(pData + 12,srcData + 9,3);
                *(pData + 15) = 0xFF;
            }
            for (idx = 0;idx < remain;idx++,pData += 4,srcData += 3)
            {
                memcpy(pData,srcData,3);
                *(pData + 3) = 0xFF;
            }
        }
```

Comment: I'm not sure about the overall algorithm but you should use pre-increment if you are not using the previous value in the statement, so use ++idx and ++r.  Though with any optimization turned on the compiler will probably do this for you.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your compiler, you may not want `memcpy` at all for such a small copy.  Here is a variant version for the body of your unrolled loop; see if it's faster:

```
uint32_t in0 = *(uint32_t*)(srcData);
uint32_t in1 = *(uint32_t*)(srcData + 4);
uint32_t in2 = *(uint32_t*)(srcData + 8);
uint32_t out0 = UINT32_C(0xFF000000) | (in0 & UINT32_C(0x00FFFFFF));
uint32_t out1 = UINT32_C(0xFF000000) | (in0 >> 24) | ((in1 & 0xFFFF) << 8);
uint32_t out2 = UINT32_C(0xFF000000) | (in1 >> 16) | ((in2 & 0xFF) << 16);
uint32_t out3 = UINT32_C(0xFF000000) | (in2 >> 8);
*(uint32_t*)(pData) = out0;
*(uint32_t*)(pData + 4) = out1;
*(uint32_t*)(pData + 8) = out2;
*(uint32_t*)(pData + 12) = out3;
```

You should also declare `srcData` and `pData` as `BYTE * restrict` pointers so the compiler will know they don't alias.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see much that you're doing that isn't necessary.  You could change the post-increments to pre-increments (`idx++` to `++idx`, for instance), but that won't have a measurable effect.

Additionally, you could use `std::copy` instead of `memcpy`.  `std::copy` has more information available to it and in theory can pick the most efficient way to copy things.  Unfortunately I don't believe that many STL implementations actually take advantage of the extra information.

The only thing that I expect would make a difference is that there's no reason to wait for one `memcpy` to finish before starting the next.  You could use OpenMP or Intel Threading Building Blocks (or a thread queue of some kind) to parallelize the loops.

Answer (score 0):

Don't call memcpy, just do the copy by hand. The function call overhead isn't worth it unless you can copy more than 3 bytes at a time.

Comment: I believe that depends on the compiler.  I think GCC will inline small, fixed-size `memcpy` calls, for example.

Comment: @Jeremiah Might be true, but why write code that's dependent on certain versions/flags for GCC?

Answer (score 0):

As far as this particular loop goes, you may want to look at a technique called [Duff's device](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device), which is a loop-unrolling technique that takes advantage of the switch construct.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe changing to a while loop instead of nested for loops:

```
BYTE *src = srcData;
BYTE *dest = pData;
int maxsrc = h*(w*3+srcPadding);
int offset = 0;
int maxoffset = w*3;
while (src+offset < maxsrc) {
    *dest++ = *(src+offset++);
    *dest++ = *(src+offset++);
    *dest++ = *(src+offset++);
    dest++;
    if (offset > maxoffset) {
        src += srcPadding;
        offset = 0;
    }
}
```